# No output from SCSS gets compiled into CSS when Live Sass compiler or sass --watch is used

Tags: css, sass, live-sass-compiler

I have freshly installed VSCode and the Live Sass Compiler extension, but whenever I press **Watch Sass**, a compilation error gets thrown in the **Output** and no *.css* file or *.css.map* gets compiled.

```
Compilation Error
There was no CSS output from sass/sass
--------------------
Watching...
--------------------
```

This is what my project directory looks like:

[image: This is what my project directory looks like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question lol.
Instead of using Sass compiler extensions, this can be done by opening the terminal in the working directory and type in:

```
sass --watch <your_sass_filename>.scss <your_output_css_filename>.css
```

both the sass and css filename can be whatever you want.

And if you see that you don't have sass installed on your system.
You can download and install node.js to allow the use of npm.
Afterwards, go to the terminal and type:

```
npm install sass
```

Answer (score 1):

Live Sass Compiler has not been maintained by the creator since 2018 and is thus outdated.

Live Sass Compiler uses Node Sass and not Dart Sass. Dart Sass is the maintained version of Sass and receives all the new features, while Node Sass is deprecated and does not.

You can install Live Sass Compiler by Glenn Marks instead which is a maintained fork of Live Sass Compiler.

[image: Picture of Live Sass Compiler by Glenn Marks]

Another alternative is the `DartJS Sass Compiler` extension

[image: DartJS Sass Compiler]